# SOAP php non wsdl procedure not present

Tags: php, linux, soap, wsdl, procedure

I have written web service in PHP. It has been working fine for couple of weeks. Today I had to change my SOAP client to be in non WSDL form, after making the following change, I am getting this annoying error:

> Procedure 'FUNCTIONNAME' not present

My code:

```
//$client = new SoapClient("STWebServiceWSDL.wsdl", array('trace' => 1));
//This is working, but why, non wsdl below not working

$client = new SoapClient(null, array('location' => "https://mysite.com/STserver.php",
                                    'uri'      => "https://mysite.com/STserver.php",
                                    'trace'=>1));
```

Please help, I could not find any solution on the Net for the whole day.

My SOAP server is like this:

```
$server = new SoapServer("STWebServiceWSDL.wsdl");
```

Comment: and where is this 'FUNCTIONNAME' code written, at least not in the lines that you have pasted

Comment: it is written in file where soapServer is created. I told you it has been working for many weeks without problem. I just don`t understand how to configure non wsdl mode.

Comment: for non wsdl , I think you will have to go wit XML-RPC mode.